# Eclipse & SVN: How to Rename Files to Uppercase?

Tags: eclipse, svn, file-rename

I'm using Eclipse and plugin Subeclipse for SVN.
I just wanted to rename a file to uppercase the name.
Example: "file_a.txt" to "FILE_A.TXT"
What should be my best practice?

I tried to right-click on the file and select "Rename"(F2) to rename then commit to SVN.
But I encountered an error:

```
Problems encountered while moving resources.
SVN: '0x00000118: Move' operation finished with error
Move 'file_a.txt' to '/project/package' was failed.
svn: File 'C:\eclipse\project\package\FILE_A.TXT' already exists
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my workaround:
For example, I want rename `abc.txt` to `Abc.txt`

1. svn rename `abc.txt` `abc.txt.temp`
2. svn commit
3. svn rename `abc.txt.temp` `Abc.txt`
4. svn commit

`rename` is same as `copy` then `delete`
You won't lost any commit history,
the time line of the file still trackable from the very beginning to now

Answer (score 2):

First of all Filename being case sensitive depends on operating system.
Windows is not case sensitive while unix is.

You have an option to change case in windows if you are using svn above 1.6, see for more details here : http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#case-change

Answer (score 2):

http://binary.freeperspective.net/countzero/2009/02/23/svn-change-filename-letters-case-only/

Changing file name with TortoiseSVN GUI:

1. Open repo-browser ( Right click on desktop and choose TortoiseSVN -> Repo-browser )
2. Enter the repository URL in text box that appear.  Click OK.
3. Use tree-view to locate directory where the file is.
4. Right click on file in file-list window and choose ‘Rename’
5. Enter new file name.

Answer (score 0):

For SVN 1.7 and up, you can use the following:

```
svn mv file_a.txt FILE_A.TXT
```

[Source](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#case-change)